# Native json4s prints stacktrace when reading illegal JSON

Tags: scala, json4s

When I use Json4s 3.2.9 native, I get a stacktrace every time it parses bad JSON in Scala. I have tests where I make sure that invalid JSON is treated correctly and now the stacktraces clutter my tests -.-, can I turn this off, or can I change to json4s jackson and turn it off?

Comment: json4s-jackson provides a `parseOpt` method which returns an `Option` and does not print the stracktrace, but rather a `None`. Have you already tried that out?

Comment: I would like no prints if that is possible.

Comment: Sorry, my phrasing was ambiguous. `parseOpt` does not print anything, it just returns a `None` in case parsing failed.

Comment: Oh thanks. Can you make this an answer and I'll accept you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseOpt` which does not print anything and returns an `Option`. In case parsing failed, it returns `None`.